# python parse `ISO_8601` time or time interval

Tags: python, datetime, parsing, iso

I need to convert

**FROM**

a list of `str`s

**TO**

a list of

- either a `datetime.datetime`
- or a `datetime.datetime` plus a `datetime.timedelta`.

The input list contains strings in `ISO_8601` [(wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The strings can either be a date or a time interval. The solution for this, that I came up with is the following:

```
import dateutil.parser

result = []
for str_ in input_list:
    if not is_time_interval_str(str_):
        result.append(dateutil.parser.parse(str_))
    else:
        result.append(parse_time_interval(str_))
```

What I am stuck with is the two functions `is_time_interval_str` and `parse_time_interval`. I have looked for python packages that implement parsing of the time intervals but I couldn't find any yet. I have checked

1. `dateutil.parser`
2. `pyiso8601`
3. `isodate`
4. `arrow`
5. `ciso8601`
6. `iso8601utils` (claims to support time intervals, but does only some)
7. `maya` (offers the functionality, but the implementation is flawed)
8. `pendulum` (claims to support time intervals, but does only some)

Some may be capable of parsing durations like `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` but none is able to parse time intervals like for example `<start>/<end>`.
6.,7. and 8. work partially also with `<start>/<end>` but none of them works with a partial `<end>` description. (example `'2007-01-10/27'`)

I considered writing my own string parser but it feels that such fundamental thing like the implementation of the `ISO_8601` should be incorporated by one of the above packages.

**Questions**

1. Should I write my own string parser with something like `map(dateutil.parser.parser, str_.split("/"))`?
2. Is there any python package capable of parsing time intervals of the `ISO_8601`?
3. I've seen solutions that use database engines for conversion of `str` to `datetime.datetime`, would this be an option for time intervals?

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date

Comment: @user1558604 thank you for the suggestion, this post pointed me to five more python packages that I tried out (I updated the list of non-working packages). But there is no solution in that question working for me, as far as I can tell.